# Email without date

Tags: gmail-api

In my use-case I must retrieve all emails from an user. But some emails don't have "Date" in their headers although gmail can display a date in the web interface. So, is there a way to retrieve this date?

Maybe Gmail sends some additional information with emails?

Comment: Can you provide exact call your making and response you're getting that's not appropriate?  I imagine message.get()?  What 'format'?  Is it really an email (and not a chat/hangout)?

Comment: It's not message.get() but the same thing, threads.get() with messages ressources. In the message ressource of this mail, there isn't header date, but it's normal because the mail haven't date headers when he is send as EML (http://pastebin.com/4XxEHaMf) . So, how gmail do to display the good date in his webinterface ? And can we retrieve this date easily with the API ?

PS : Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now retrieve the `internalDate` through the Gmail API, which represents the time the message was created at Google is ms.

List the messages:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response:**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "14ea5fa7f99dc9e6",
   "threadId": "14ea5fa7f99dc9e6"
  }, ...
}
```

And get the messages individually, asking for the `internalDate`.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/14ea5fa7f99dc9e6?fields=internalDate&access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response:**

```
{
 "internalDate": "1437303729000" // This is the time in ms it was created.
}
```

If you are working with threads, you can get the `internalDate` of each message in the thread by simply issuing a Users.thread: get-request.